# Disk image creation from folder: error 28 - no space left on device

Tags: disk-utility, disk-space, archive, disk-image

I wanted to create a full copy of my MacBook Air in a disk image for archive.
I can't save the disk from the booted system, so I restarted my Mac in Recovery mode (keys Command and R) on boot.
From the recovery menu, I can launch Disk Utility, I select the 'Macintosh HD' drive, give the image a name, select the options "not compressed" and "read only". I select the destination disk and let the process begins...
After a long time, just before ending the process, I have a message "error 28: No space left on Device".

My MBA has a 250 GB SSD disk, I have a 50 GB iCloud account, so in the case iCloud Drive is saved too (I don't think so...), there is just about maximum 300 GB to save.
I tried to save on a Drobo (which claims being 64 TB in size, and have more than 2TB free), and on an empty 1TB Drive, and had the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...
It seems that APFS and/or iCloud Drive has killed the ability to create a disk image from an entire disk...
I tried lots of things, even Disk Utility's Restore in a freshly-created disk-image failed.

So I did it the hard way, with the terminal

- Creation of a disk image (lot bigger than the drive) `hdiutil create -size 500g -fs HFS+ -volname Clone\ Macintosh\ HD /Volumes/WD\ 1To/Clone\ MBA.dmg`
- Mounting the disk image
  `hdiutil attach /Volumes/WD\ 1To/Clone\ MBA.dmg`
- Note the `/dev/disk_s_` path to unmount it
- Save the disk with RSYNC (options and exclusions found on the internet)
  `sudo rsync -vaEx /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/ /Volumes/Clone\ Macintosh\ HD --exclude=/Volumes/* --exclude=/Network/* --exclude=/automount/* --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/private/tmp/* --exclude=/private/var/run/* --exclude=/private/var/spool/postfix/* --exclude=/private/var/vm/* --exclude=.Spotlight-*/ --exclude=.Trashes --exclude=*/.Trash --exclude=/afs/* --exclude=/cores/*`
- The result was bigger than the original drive (probably due to APFS which have some tricks to not duplicate data when copying a file, and certainly due to the saving of documents that are on iCloud Drive but not really on the disk: icons with a cloud badge)
- Detach the image `hdiutil detach /dev/disk3s2`
- Then I tried to shrink the disk image from the command-line, but neither `hdiutil compact`, not `hdiutil resize` worked (errors)
- Then I tried to resize with Disk Utility, but it didn't work too (disk utility claimed it was done, but the size didn't change at all)
- So I converted the image to read-only with Disk Utility (in fact, it duplicated the image), and now I have a shrinked disk-image of my entire startup disk!

Lot of wasted time, it used to be easyer